# Achieving heat vision in OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, computer-vision, heat

I am doing a project and my professor said "try to use heat vision as well". I am doing the whole project in OpenCV, and no way of dropping it.

I have no idea about how to do heat vision. I got only $50-$70 to spend for any device because rest is spent for other devices I am using.

So my question is, how to do heat vision? I am now identifying human using OpenCV with the help of videos captured by a normal webcam but heat vision also suggested by professor. Is there any way of doing heat vision in OpenCV? What kind of cjeap device do I need? Device should have a C# or C++ api as well.

Comment: If you have any doubts about why I am asking this much of questions, please visit my profile, you will understand :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is your prof referring to using infra red combined with vision? In that case, all you need to do is remove the IR filter from your camera. Without this filter, infra red radiation goes through to the sensor and is clearly visible in the image. You can refer to [this article](http://www.diyphotography.net/are-you-brave-enough-to-ir-ize-your-camera) for a start. I'm sure it's easier on a webcam :)

Comment: wow, Thanks for the reply. +1 from me. Does this work as a thermal cam? yea, I got 2 webcams but anyplace I can get this BUILT-IN? I only do hardware programming, bad at creatig those.

Comment: sorry for asking this, but will these cams will do it? http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_sacat=0&_from=R40&_mPrRngCbx=1&_nkw=infrared+web+camera&_lncat=0&_arm=1&_armm=94&_ruu=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com%2Fsch%2FElectrical-Test-Equipment-%2F92074%2Fi.html%3F_from%3DR40%26_mPrRngCbx%3D1%26_nkw%3Dinfrared%2Bweb%2Bcamera%26_arr%3D1&_armi=Electrical+%26+Test+Equipment

Comment: The cameras you listed use the infrared only for motion sensing, and for triggering the "normal" camera to start capturing video. So I don't think they will be useful for what you need. Unfortunately, thermal imaging cameras are very expensive, so a DIY solution would be the best bet. There are loads of cheap DIY tricks on youtube, this one (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMpgeFoYbBI) for instance. These are not very difficult to do.